# Finder thinks item exists after it's already been deleted (Samba)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, samba, finder

First, I copied `foo.7z` to my SMB share (zfs zpool, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Samba 4.7.6) through finder. Over SSH, I moved it elsewhere on the server. I tried copying a different `foo.7z` again to the same location as the old one, but finder says:

`The operation can’t be completed because an item with the name “foo.7z” already exists.`

This is not true, as the file isn't there anymore after I moved it.

Here's my smb.conf on the ubuntu server:

```
[global]
mangled names = no
dos charset = CP850
access based share enum = yes
unix extensions = no
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:model = MacPro
unix charset = UTF-8
fruit:resource = xattr
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

[SMB Share]
 comment = SMB Share
 path = /tank
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
 guest ok = no
 ea support = yes
 vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
 map archive = no
 spotlight = yes
 readdir_attr:aapl_rsize = yes
 readdir_attr:aapl_finder_info = yes
 readdir_attr:aapl_max_access = yes
```

Using High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 0):

Some unix commands use a database of data instead of searching for it.For example locate uses a prebuilt database to search your disk. Much faster but database may be slow to update and hence you'd be using a dated set of filenames for example. The database may take a day or two to update.

Comment: So, bascially there's nothing I can do? Is that just the quirk of using samba in this manner?